# What educational requirements (if any) are required to be a juror in the USA?

Tags: united-states, jury

Searching online I found the following information:

> To be legally qualified for jury service, an individual must:
>
> ...
>
> be adequately proficient in English to satisfactorily complete the
> juror qualification form;
>
> [Source](https://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/jury-service/juror-qualifications#:%7E:text=To%20be%20legally%20qualified%20for%20jury%20service%2C%20an,primarily%20in%20the%20judicial%20district%20for%20one%20year%3B)

Following up with another search, I found this JUROR QUALIFICATION FORM (Commonwealth of Kentucky)

https://kycourts.gov/resources/legalforms/LegalForms/005A.pdf

[image]

I have highlighted in blue the box marked `Level of Education Completed`

**Question**

In what way and to what extent is the level of education used when deciding whether someone is fit to be a juror?

Comment: I am pretty sure there are no requirements, and it would probably be unconstitutional if there were.  I don't know how to prove the negative, though.  My assumption is that this is partly just for statistical purposes, and partly so that the attorneys on both sides can take education into account when deciding whether to challenge a juror.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the level is meant to sort the jury pool and generate a mixed jury - you don't want to need to pick 6 from a jury pool of 3 professors of physics, 2 medical doctors, 4 veterinarians, a coroner, 3 doctorates in chemistry and a nuclear scientists - that pool in no way is "average". Though there is a need to be of having the mental capacity to understand the proceedings or you might be disqualified.

Comment: In the US, juror requirements and qualifications will differ depending upon the state in which the juror will serve. The federal system (the US has a separate system of federal courts) will have yet another set of requirements and qualifications.